# How to change border around each paragraph <p> section dynamically from dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

The following fiddle attached allows text to be pasted into a `<textarea>` and converted into paragraphs on button click.

---

Is it possible, within the fiddle, to create a dropdown list `<select>` where a border can be created around each paragraph section and updated from the dropdown list dynamically to other borders, according to the users choice?

If the an updated fiddle could be provided would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

Thank You!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdCyq/15/)

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="text_land" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; margin-bottom:30px;">xzxz</div>
<textarea style="widht:95%;"></textarea>
<button>Go</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var i = 200;
        while (theText.length > 200) {
            console.log('looping');
            while (theText.charAt(i) !== '.') {
                i++;   
            }

            console.log(i);
            $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, i+1) + "</p>");
            theText = theText.substring(i+1);
            i = 200;
        }

        $('#text_land').append("<p>" + theText + "</p>");
    });

});
```

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/zdCyq/62/?

Comment: @Rajesh -  The stack overflow question is different from this question. The aim of this question is to enable borders around a paragraph, whereas, the other question was for changing the color and text size of the paragraph element.

Comment: @Dave answers on previous post shows how to update css properties of a tag, which is even applicable for border. Please try on your own and if you face difficulties, then ask. Dont ask similar questions

Comment: @Rajesh - Thanks for the info!.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var i = 200;
        while (theText.length > 200) {
            console.log('looping');
            while (theText.charAt(i) !== '.') {
                i++;   
            }
            
            console.log(i);
            $("#text_land").append("<p target='tobebordered'>" + theText.substring(0, i+1) + "</p>");
            theText = theText.substring(i+1);
            i = 200;
        }
        
        $('#text_land').append("<p target='tobebordered'>" + theText + "</p>");
    })
    
    $('#borders').on('change', function () {
        var border = $(this).val();
        $('[target="tobebordered"]').each(function(idx, obj) {
            $(obj).removeClass('dotted dashed');
            $(obj).addClass(border);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.dashed {
   border: 1px dashed #000
}

.dotted {
   border: 1px dotted #000
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="text_land" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; margin-bottom:30px;">xzxz</div>
    <textarea style="widht:95%;"></textarea><br>
    <button>Go</button><br>
    <select id="borders">
        <option value='dashed'>Dashed</option>
        <option value='dotted'>Dotted</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Hope this helps!**